3D viewer in Apple vision pro with Unity
I am trying to rotate, scale, and tranform 3d objects in the apple vision pro with Unity, but the problem is that the the scaling and rotating some times they do the opposite.
So what I should happen is using 2 hands you will pich and move the hand from the right to left as a cricle and what is expcted that the 3d object will do the same thing but goes into the opposite direction sometimes.
I am wondering if there is any built in code that I can use for this and here is the code I used if you want to edit it.
public class RotateObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Touch primaryTouch;
    private Touch secondaryTouch;
    private float initialDistance;
    private GameObject selectedObject;
    [SerializeField]
    private float rotateFactor; // Adjust as needed

    void OnEnable()
    {
        EnhancedTouchSupport.Enable();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Touch.activeTouches.Count == 2)
        {
            primaryTouch = Touch.activeTouches[0];
            secondaryTouch = Touch.activeTouches[1];
            SpatialPointerState touchData1 = EnhancedSpatialPointerSupport.GetPointerState(primaryTouch);
            SpatialPointerState touchData2 = EnhancedSpatialPointerSupport.GetPointerState(secondaryTouch);

            if (touchData1.targetObject != null && touchData1.Kind != SpatialPointerKind.Touch)
            {
                print(primaryTouch.phase);
                if (primaryTouch.phase == TouchPhase.Began || secondaryTouch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
                {
                    selectedObject = touchData1.targetObject;
                    initialDistance = touchData1.inputDevicePosition.z - touchData2.inputDevicePosition.z;

                }
                if (primaryTouch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved || secondaryTouch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
                {
                    float currentDistance = touchData1.inputDevicePosition.z - touchData2.inputDevicePosition.z;

                    float deltaXDistance = (currentDistance - initialDistance);

                    print(deltaXDistance * rotateFactor);
                    touchData1.targetObject.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, deltaXDistance * rotateFactor);
                    initialDistance = currentDistance;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Reset initial distance when not pinching
            initialDistance = 0f;
            selectedObject = null;
        }
    }
}

